# Graph - Non Simple Path , Longest Path

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, graph, shortest-path

I am trying to solve finding longest path in a Graph. Even in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) its mentioned that we are trying to find **longest simple path** .

**Simple Path** is a path where no vertices/edges repeats.

**Non-Simple Path** is a path where vertices/edges can repeat. I can think of either cycle or circuit as non-simple path . And since circuit is always have cycle.

Questions :

1. Can i say for a directed/un-directed graph. A non simple path always have cycle?
2. And because there is a cycle in non-simple path , longest non-simple path or a graph is not possible? (Just like we don't have an algorithm to find shortest distance for a graph with negative edge?)

Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct: a non-simple path will always contain a cycle. Take the first instance of the first repeated node on the non-simple path and follow the path until you revisit that node; that's your cycle!

And yes, for that reason the longest nonsimple path in a graph is not always defined. In fact, it's never defined in any graph containing at least one edge.

Note that finding the longest simple path in a graph is known to be **NP**-hard, and there are no known efficient algorithms for the problem. However, there are some nice dynamic programming solutions that reduce the runtime over true brute-force, and clever algorithms like [color-coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color-coding) can be used to find long paths somewhat efficiently.

Comment: However, there are some nice dynamic programming solutions that reduce the runtime over true brute-force, and clever algorithms like color-coding can be used to find long paths somewhat efficiently. -- you mean Longest Simple Path right?

Comment: @Jeevi Yep! Usually, people use the term "longest path" to mean "longest simple path," though admittedly that's technically incorrect.